# How can I redirect to the Contact's page after adding them to a Campaign?

Tags: apex, custom-button, redirect

List button url:

```
/apex/CreateNewcm?save_new=1&noOveride=1&ContactId={!Contact.Id}&ContactName={!Contact.Name}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="CampaignMember" extensions="SaveAndReturnController">
<script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveAndReturn}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
```

Extension:

```
public with sharing class SaveAndReturnController
{
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public SaveAndReturnController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
        PageReference cancel = controller.cancel();
        controller.save();
        return cancel;
    }
}
```

This latest attempt (out of many) has come closest (trying to emulate how the 'Cancel' button returns us to the original page), but instead of redirecting to the Contact's page, it redirects to the Home page. I don't understand why this is?

Edit: Hm..I thought the 'Cancel' button returned the user to the Contact's page. Turns out it returns them to the Home page too. So no more confusion on that count, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return to view page of the Contact record with the use of controller.view() if you are using instance of StandardController as `Contact`.

```
public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
        controller.save();
        return controller.view();
    }
```

Refer [StandardController Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm)

**Edit**

To navigate to Contact's view page, first capture the contactId and, use this:

```
 PageReference pRef =  (new ApexPages.StandardController (new Contact(Id=contactId))).view();               
 pRef.setRedirect(true); 
 return pRef;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the link especially. Played around a little, and now I understand my mistake. Except now it doesn't redirect anywhere - it just saves on the vf page? Also, may I recommend this edit, as the code in your answer didn't work for me (does it work for you?):                                                       
      public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
        PageReference view = controller.view();
        controller.save();
        return view;
    
    }

Comment: PageReference pg = controller.view(); pg.setRedirect(true); return pg; can you check this

Comment: Same result - I click save, the record is created, but no redirection: I stay on the same page, and the input fields are greyed out.

Comment: Checked^ Outlined the result in my last comment.

Comment: @SantanuBoral `return controller.save().setRedirect(true);` is a shortcut for your code, assuming no save errors, of course.

Comment: actually when I do this testing from visualforce it works perfectly, no sure why he is facing issue from custom button